# How to pass multiple input values and attach the results back to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, api, dataframe

I have an API to which I should pass a value and get the latitude and longitude back from the API and attach back to data frame . The API allows only pass one value at time and retrieve the value.
I have around 100 plus city names for which get the latitude and longitude.

I want to pass the one input at a time to the API and store into the dataframe and append with other outputs.How can this be achieved by iterating multiple inputs

**Input dataframe**

```
Input.head(4)
    ID  CITY
    23  Lyon
    45  Paris
    56  Mumbai
    76  Chennai
```

**API Data retrieval Code**

```
 import requests

    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Api-Key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    }

    params = (
        ('provider', 'google'),
    )

    data = '{ "address": "Singapore"}'

    response = requests.post('https://example.com/geocoder/geocode', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)

import json
d = json.loads(response.text)
df =pd.DataFrame([d['position']])
```

**My expected  output**

```
ID  CITY     lat    lon
23  Lyon     1.352  103.819
45  Paris    1.456  117.345
56  Mumbai   1.345  118 .675
76  Chennai  1.678  117.678
```

**Sample Response from API**

```
'{"position": {"lat": 1.352083, "lon": 103.819836}, "mapView": {"N": 1.4784001, "E": 104.0945001, "S": 1.1496, "W": 103.594}}\n'
```

Comment: I also have similar issue.

Comment: can you provide a sample `response.text` returned from the api ?

Comment: @bhaskarc,`'{"position": {"lat": 1.352083, "lon": 103.819836}, "mapView": {"N": 1.4784001, "E": 104.0945001, "S": 1.1496, "W": 103.594}}\n'`. I have also updated the question with same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import json
ids = [23,45,56,76]
cities = ['Lyon','Paris','Mumbai','Chennal',] 
lat_data = {}
lon_data = {}
df = pd.DataFrame( list(zip(ids, cities)), columns =['ID', 'City']) 

for city in cities:
  #this is where you run your api calls
  headers = {
   'accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': 'Api-Key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  }
  params = ( ('provider', 'google'),)
  data = '{ "address":' + city +  '}'
  response = '{"position": {"lat": 1.352083, "lon": 103.819836}, "mapView": {"N": 1.4784001, "E": 104.0945001, "S": 1.1496, "W": 103.594}}\n'
  j = json.loads(response)
  lat_data[city] = j["position"]["lat"]
  lon_data[city] = j["position"]["lon"]

df['lat'] = df['City'].map(lat_data)  
df['lon'] = df['City'].map(lon_data)  

print(df)
```

This will output:

```
   ID     City       lat         lon
0  23     Lyon  1.352083  103.819836
1  45    Paris  1.352083  103.819836
2  56   Mumbai  1.352083  103.819836
3  76  Chennal  1.352083  103.819836
```

Basically, create two dicts `lat_data` and `lon_data`, then run through all cities in a loop and store city name as key and latitude and longitude data in the two dicts created.

Then map it back to your pandas dataframe like so `df['lat'] = df['City'].map(lat_data)`

Comment: ,How would I replace this peace of code `data = '{ "address": "Singapore"}'` with your code

Comment: Should I just replace  `data = '{ "address": "Singapore"}'` with `data = '{ "address": "cities"}'`

Comment: yes within loop replace with  data = '{ "address": city}'. Not cities and not within quote. Note we are looping through cities and in each loop we have city name in the variable city

Comment: I am getting intend error while pasting the other piece code..`params = (
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent`. Can you modify the example if possible with correct indentation

Comment: this is a fully working code. the indentation error is happening at your end. If you simply copy paste and run my code, it works out of the box. The error is in your code in the line `params = ( ^ IndentationErro`

Comment: Modified the code to include your lines. Now simply replace the response line with your api call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202373/discussion-between-ashok-eapen-and-bhaskarc).